# How to get event from IBAction method

Tags: objective-c, ios

I've connected a UITextField to an action method for a number of events. To enable me to check what the specific event was I used the sender: event: method type. However, I am now at a loss as to how to determine what the actual event that triggered the method was. What's the secret?

Answer (score 1):

The "event" is the one passed to your action method, but I assume your real question is which  of the `UIControlEvents` caused the action. `UIEvent` and `UIControlEvents` are unrelated. The target/action pattern provides a `UIEvent`. If you want to handle different `UIControlEvents` differently, you should implement different actions for them.

Remember, the target/action mechanism comes from `UIResponder`. `UIControlEvents` are related to `UIControl`.

Comment: I actually came here looking to find the UIEvent (for other purposes), from within my `-(IBAction) callback: (id) sender` method.  Is it gettable?

Comment: You need to rename your method to `-(IBAction)action:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent*)event`. Then the event will be passed to you. See `[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent]` for docs.