# Find UIControl.Event that produced an action

Tags: ios, uicontrolevents

In iOS you can assign an action method to several `UIControl` events, eg.

```
              ...........   

        self.addTarget(self,
            action: #selector(onTouch(sender:forEvent:)),
            for: .allTouchEvents)

              ...........


   @objc func onTouch(sender: UIControl, forEvent event: UIEvent) {
       // Which UIControl.Event ?
   }
```

Is it possible in action method to find out, which `UIControl.Event` triggered the action?

Comment: see this for help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31405771/ios-fetch-uibutton-current-uicontroleventtype-at-selector

Comment: Anbu.Karthik  That's really helpful, though it doesn't give a direct answer to this question. Actually I expected that a single method invocation can take place  several events at once. I wonder if the event history will be cleared for the next call.

Comment: again once see this for help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31122418/in-swift-how-do-you-detect-which-uicontrolevents-triggered-the-action

Comment: Oh, yes, that's the one! How could I overlook it!  Mark this question as dupplicate, or I will delete it:)

Comment: Anbu.Karthik I use the approach from the first link and it does exactly what I need. I would mark that as an answer, if I could.

Comment: sure, choice is urs

Comment: Try Using Switch for each action Event and execute different code on trigger of different events